# Margin tool tip in stylesheet looks off for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012

Shouldn't the tool tip say top|right|bottom|left?

[image]

This makes more sense to me:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, this helped me remember `t.r.b.l.` like trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will only suggest keywords, like as `auto`, `inherit`, and `initial`, the only other options are values (e.g. `5px`, `10em`, etc).

`top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` are not values for the `margin:` property. You must be thinking of `margin-top:`, `margin-right:`, `margin-bottom:` and `margin-left:`, which are different properties entirely.